# Need to update values individually in the dynamic circular progress bar

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

```css
.box .percent svg circle
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 10;
    stroke: #000;
    transform: translate(5px,5px);
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-dasharray:440;
    stroke-dashoffset: 440; 
}
.box .percent svg circle:nth-child(1)
{
     stroke-dashoffset:0;
     stroke: #f3f3f3;
}
.box .percent svg circle:nth-child(2)
{
     stroke-dashoffset:calc(440 - (440*75)/100);
     stroke: #03a9f4;
}
```

```html
<!-- ***********************************************Dashboard Code This code is repeated for different dashboards*************************************************-->
    <div class="box">
        <div class="percent">
            <svg>
                <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
                <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
            </svg>
            <div class="number">
                <h2>87<span>%</span></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="text">Dashboard 1</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have created a dynamic circular progress bar. I need to update the value individually for different dashboards in the CSS.

using the same HTML code for different dashboards. The same value of 75% is updated to all the dashboards. I want to fill different values to different dashboards, for that how to declare "nth-child for different dashboards in CSS"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSh63.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Paulie_D Kindly see the image, in that all the dashboard are displayed with 75% in the progress bar. I wanted to create individual "svg circle:nth-child(1)" for different dashboards. How to do it?

Comment: How are you changing te values. Seems to me you need javascript